# Outputting data from a Hash Map to ListView in Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, listview, hashmap

I'm very new to programming through Android Studio (Java) and completing an assignment that requires an endless list for a "Product inventory". The Values, <String, Integer> Which are Product and quantity are retrieved from a local database (room). The expectation is that the values are first stored in a HashMap then output to a ListView. Unfortunately the learning material provided did not cover this process, and I have been unable to find a method online that I understand and can get to work. The code of what I have tried is below:

```
    private String product;
    private Integer quantity;
    private ListView inventoryListView;
    private SimpleAdapter listAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory_main_menu);
        inventoryDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
                InventoryDatabase.class, "inventorydb").allowMainThreadQueries().build();

        // Set references to widgets
        final TextView welcome = findViewById(R.id.textViewWelcome);
        Button buttonManageInventory = findViewById(R.id.buttonManageInventory);
        Button buttonLogout = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogOut);


        //Set welcome message to active user and change color
        welcome.setTextColor(MainActivity.activeUserFavColor);
        welcome.setText("Welcome " + MainActivity.activeUsername);
        
        // Query Database + Method for Product & Quantity
        List<Inventory> inventoryList = inventoryDatabase.dao().getInventory();

        for (Inventory inv : inventoryList) {
            product = inv.getProduct();
            quantity = inv.getQuantity();

            HashMap<String, Integer> inventory = new HashMap<>();
```

I have learnt how to retrieve info from the database via a List but I feel I should be able to complete the import direct to the HashMap.

As for the ListView, I have seen the use of a SimpleAdapter to allow the conversion from HashMap  to ListView to work, but have no experience in using this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to show it in listview simply you can use your list with `arrayadapter` why you want to use hashmap? It would be better to use recyclerview instead of listview for better performance.

Comment: The reason a Hashmap is used was due to the requirements set out in the assignment explicitly requesting a hashmap. A listview was suggested by someone else to use as the output, however, I will try a recycler view instead. Thanks